# pointer decrement inside while loop with semicolon vs without semicolon

Tags: c++, c, pointers, while-loop

```
void* My_memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t size)
{
    char *p1 = (char *)dest;
    char *p2 = (char *)src;

    if(NULL == p1 || NULL == p2)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    p2 += size;

    while(p2 != src &&  --p2 != dest)
    if(p2 != src)
    {
        printf("inside IF \n");
        p1 += size;
        p2  = (char *)src + size;

        while(size--)
        {
            *(--p1) = *(--p2);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("inside ELSE \n");
        while(size--)
        {
            *(p1++) = *(p2++);
        }
    }

    return dest;
}

int main(void)
{
   char dest[15];
   memset(dest, 0, 15);

   printf("Enter the string : ");
   scanf("%s", dest);

    My_memmove(dest+3, dest, strlen(dest));
    printf("dest+3 : %s \n", dest+3);

    return (0);
}
```

Could you please explain what is happening when there is no semicolon after while(p2 != src &&  --p2 != dest)
Because the above program works for all the inputs expect for the input of size 4

RESULTS:

Enter the string : 12

inside IF

dest+3 : 12

Enter the string : 123

inside IF

dest+3 : 123

Enter the string : 1234

dest+3 : 4

Enter the string : 12345

inside IF

dest+3 : 12345

Enter the string : 123456

inside IF

dest+3 : 123456

Memory layout after p2+size when the size is 7

```
                      p2+--+
                           | 
        src+-+ dst++       |
             |     |       |
             v     v       v
            ++-----+-------+--------+
            |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8| ... |
            +-----------------------+
dest[15] -> |a|b|c|d|e|f|g|0|0| ... |
            +-----------------------+
```

Comment: `while(predicate) body`, in the first the body isn't given.  In the second, the body is `;`.

Comment: This is an apples-and-oranges comparison.  Statement 2 is useless and does nothing.  Statement 1 is incomplete, so we can't say what it does.

Comment: @SRIKANTH Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the difference.

Comment: `str` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: Updated with runnable code and results

Comment: @SRI I've tried to clarify the issue with your code in an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

With a `while` (or `for` or `if`), you have two options for the body. You can either use curly braces for a multi-statement body:

```
while(condition) {
    multi;
    statement;
    body;
}
```

Or you can leave off the curly braces and the next statement will be considered the body of the loop. This can be nice with good formatting for short bodies:

```
if(condition)
    return thing;
```

But it can also be confusing with bad formatting:

```
if(condition)
    thing += thing2;
    return thing;
```

Only that first statement (`thing += thing2`) is actually in the body of the `if` there. The `return` will get run every time regardless.

A semicolon by itself is the null statement. It is a full statement in its own right, but it does nothing. So

```
while(condition);
```

Is the same as

```
while(condition) {
    ;
}
```

Your other example without the semicolon will pull the next statement found in the code and use it as the body of the loop.

---

In response to your update, let's take a look at the memory of your string through a run of the function with input "abcd":

```
        src--+ dst-+
             |     |
             v     v
            ++-----+----------------+
            |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8| ... |
            +-----------------------+
dest[15] -> |a|b|c|d|0|0|0|0|0| ... |
            +-----------------------+
```

Note that `size` here is 4, so when you do `char *p2 = (char *)src;` and `p2 += size;`, your pointers look like:

```
       p2+--+
            |
src+-+ dst++|
     |     ||
     v     vv
    ++-----+----------------+
    |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8| ... |
    +-----------------------+
    |a|b|c|d|0|0|0|0|0| ... |
    +-----------------------+
```

And then you do:

```
while(p2 != src &&  --p2 != dst)
```

Well guess what, `--p2` is exactly `dst`! So your loop ends without ever once getting run and you just return `dst`, which is a pointer to the last character in the string.

This is one of the many problems with trying to copy a string within itself. Your source and destination are overlapping!

Comment: Thanks!. I got the point. But, as per the behavior of while loop, If the length is x (x > 3) then the if-else block should be executed (x-3) times. But what ever is the length, the if-else block is being executed only once. could you please explain ?

Comment: @SRI please reread the second half of my answer again. Your while loop condition depends on `--p2 != dst`, but the very first time the condition is run, that is false. So your if-else is never once run (the loop is never entered).

Comment: Thank you, but <the very first time the condition is run, that is false>, This happens only when the size is 4, If the size is greater than 4, lets assume the size to be 7 then the condition holds true for 3 iterations and then on the fourth iteration the condition becomes false. Hence if-else block should be executed for 3 times. But this is not happening. In the question, I have added memory lay out when the size is 7.

Comment: @SRI "*lets assume the size to be 7 then the condition holds true for 3 iterations*" nope. The condition, `p2 != src &&  --p2 != dest` is true the *first* time you enter the loop, but then you run `while(size--) { *(--p1) = *(--p2); }` which decrements `p2`, `size` times. I'm going to be honest with you here, this code is a mess. You have a nested loop for some reason, and that strange loop up top. I'd strongly suggest starting over here. Or if this is a class project, seeking help from your professor.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I have finally understood the whole mess I have created. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> `while(p2 != src && --p2 != dest)`

Without the terminating semicolon, the loop is executing the next statement on *each iteration*. With the semicolon, the next statement will only be executed *once* when the loop ends. The exact difference will depend on what that statement is.

```
int x = 5, int y = 0;
while (x--)
++y;
```

Without the semicolon, `++y` happens on each iteration (x = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1) so y = 5. Add the semicolon and it only happens after the loop completes, giving y = 1.

Note that if `++y` is on the same line or not, indented or not, has no relevance to C or C++.

Comment: I have verified the next statement is executing only once.

Comment: Then in the case you verified it only looped once. This is what the language does, that `if` and `else` in your updated example code is for every loop. See this runnable example https://rextester.com/EVS72895

Comment: I got the point, but something is not correct in my code. if or else block is executing only once. Updated the runnable code and results. I am clueless.